# Django - set ForeignKey deferrable foreign key constraint in SQLite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I seem to be stuck with creating an initialy deferrable foreign key relationship between two models in Django and using SQLite3 as my backend storage.

Consider this simple example. This is what *models.py* looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class Investigator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    investigator = models.ForeignKey(Investigator)
```

And this is what the output from *sqlall* looks like:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "moo_investigator" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(250) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "moo_project" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    "investigator_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "moo_investigator" ("id")
)
;
CREATE INDEX "moo_project_a7e50be7" ON "moo_project" ("investigator_id");
COMMIT;
```

"DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED" is missing from the *investigator_id* column in the *project* table. What am I doing wrong?

p.s. I am new to Python and Django - using Python version 2.6.1 Django version 1.4 and SQLite version 3.6.12

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is now the default. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/803840abf7dcb6ac190f021a971f1e3dc8f6792a/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py#L16

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite backend does not add `"DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED"`. Check [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/__init__.py#L503)

Comment: can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730907/getting-django-db-utils-integrityerror-insert-or-update-on-table-violates-forei

Comment: I deleted it. If you can help please let me know

Comment: @vaibhavjain Yes PG enforces that. You could either adding the missing FK or remove the FK constraint that causes the problem (although the root problem is your data does not obey to the data schema).

Comment: yes `alter table tablename drop constraint constraintname, add constraint constraintname foreign key (packet_id) references girvi_packet(id) on delete set null;` I am doing that. It is set by a 3rd party tool. Thanks.